# Mainactivity.cs cannot locate folder holding xml file

Tags: c#, android, xamarin-studio

I'm following a tutorial for Xamarin-studio using VS 2015 CE. I added a new folder called Menu under resources folder and added to it an xml file called popMenu. In MainActivity.cs I try pass the file like this:`menu.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popMenu);`but it cannot locate the Menu folder. It also did not generate an Id for it in Resource.Designer.cs
Any ideas will be welcome.

Comment: Sometimes I have a similar bug. Try to exclude the file from the project and include it again. Might work

Comment: @user1845593 thanks, but did not work.